# converting OpenCv rectangle points into ios coordinates

Tags: ios, opencv

I am doing a app like cam scanner

I am able to find and draw a rectangle on the given image
using

cv::rectangle( image, cv::Point(fx1,fy1), cv::Point(fx2,fy2), Scalar( 255, 0, 0 ), +3, 4 );

Now I printed the point fx1,fy1 & fx2,fy2

(fx1,fy1) = 316,464

(fx2,fy1) = 2074,464

(fx2,fy2) = 2074,2864

(fx1,fy2) = 316,2864

With these point i see a rectangle drawn neatly.

Now I need to use these points for other layer to make a crop functionality.

I see these points are too large for iOS frame size(iPhone Retina 3.5inch)

How to convert the points to ios world coordinates. I am confused please guide me

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer myself..

it was my mistake

The Points(fx1,fy1) & (fx2,fy2) are rectangle point drwan on the given Image

So, accordingly we should convert the point by simple math to ios frame size and it works

Comment: can u explain how u converted these points.Even iam facing these same issues

Comment: Lets say with rectangular image be size (1500 X 800) and point fx1 = 300. for iPad Landscape (1024 X 768 ). Converting fx1 to ipad point is (1024 X 300)/1500 = ? you get fx1 for ipad. pls upvote. Thanks.

Comment: How u got 300. And one more the cv::point which we get are in vector??also i dont know the size of image. Can u share ur example. I am stuck on this final step. I tried to find in google bt no luck

Comment: sorry, I worked on open cv an year ago. First get cv::points, convert it to scalar. then convert to ios device co-ordinates.

Comment: i dont think your formula is correct.i already tries.Like inma scenario ma image size is (3264*2448) an iphone 5 resolution is 640*1136 i tries finding out cordinates but dey are not mapp to actuaL CORDINATES .Its been 5 days i am struggling dude,any kinfd of help will be great thanbks

Comment: Hey Guys any luck on the above issue, In my case I am trying to convert the opencv coordinates to iPhone.